# Error occurred in deployment step 'Install SharePoint Add-in': Could not find a part of the path

Tags: provider-hosted-app, visual-studio-2017

I am receiving the above error when trying to deploy a provider hosted add-in to the SP site. The error started appearing after the Visual studio 2017 update from ver.:15.2 to ver.:15.4. New empty app deploys successfully.

The missing path is similar to:

```
"C:\code\SPApplication\bin\Debug\app.publish\4.1.1.0\SPApplication.app".
```

In the "bin\Debug" there is no "app.publish" folder.

I switched the output of the studio to greater detail and compared the output of working (empty template) vs. non-working app:

```
2>RemoveEmptyCodeFile:
2>  Deleting file "obj\Debug\\96dfa18c-b6b1-47cb-baa1-504b623c58d6.cs".

----This is missing in the non-working app----
2>CleanPackage:
2>  Removing directory "pkg\Debug\".
2>  Removing directory "pkgobj\Debug\".
2>TransformSourceFiles:
2>  Creating directory "pkg\Debug\".
2>  Creating directory "pkgobj\Debug\".
2>MergeSearchConfigurationFiles:
2>Skipping target "MergeSearchConfigurationFiles" because it has no outputs.
2>PackageSharePointApp:
2>  Directory "bin\Debug\OfficeAppManifests\" doesn't exist. Skipping.
2>  Successfully created package at: C:\code\temp\SharePointAddIn1\SharePointAddIn1\bin\Debug\SharePointAddIn1.debugapp
----End of missing part----

3>------ Deploy started: Project: SharePointAddIn1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
```

So far I have:
- Checked the permissions of the folders. Everything looks good.
- Visual Studio is ran as Administrator...
- Tried repairing and then re-installing the Visual Studio
- Clean and install ver.: 15.3 (couldn't find a way to downgrade to 15.2)
- Compared the project settings of both projects

Does anybody have an idea what could be wrong or at least what could I check next?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the "IsPackaging" parameter ends up being "false".

Adding the:
`<IsPackaging>true</IsPackaging>`
to the project file forced the app package to build successfully. However I am now getting the "Unknown app identifier error" as the client id is not registered in the SharePoint.